# R plot/graph: Layout text and numbers instead of plotting points

Tags: r, plot, text, layout, label

I have a data frame called Lexisres that consists of birth, marriage, and death counts for cohorts and periods.

```
Lexisres <- structure(list(Cohort = c(1760L, 1760L, 1760L, 1760L, 1760L, 
1760L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1780L, 1780L, 
1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 
1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 
1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 
1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 1820L, 1820L, 1820L, 1820L, 
1820L, 1820L, 1820L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 
1840L, 1840L, 1840L, 1840L, 1840L, 1850L, 1850L, 1850L, 1850L, 
1860L, 1860L, 1860L, 1870L, 1870L, 1870L, 1880L), Births = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 
69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 
331L, 331L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 
508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 469L, 469L, 469L, 
469L, 469L, 469L, 469L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 595L, 
595L, 595L, 595L, 595L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 
361L, 361L, 361L, 1L), Period = c(1810L, 1820L, 1830L, 1840L, 
1850L, 1860L, 1810L, 1820L, 1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1810L, 
1820L, 1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1810L, 1820L, 
1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1810L, 1820L, 
1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1820L, 1830L, 
1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 
1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 
1890L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 
1890L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1880L, 1890L, 1890L, 1890L), Marriages = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 34L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 67L, 236L, 24L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 160L, 
272L, 35L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 207L, 251L, 45L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 137L, 296L, 34L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 184L, 330L, 35L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 255L, 289L, 49L, 0L, 0L, 174L, 429L, 53L, 0L, 232L, 538L, 
0L, 0L, 361L, 1L), Deaths = c(5L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 5L, 3L, 13L, 
25L, 24L, 44L, 33L, 6L, 13L, 21L, 28L, 39L, 40L, 44L, 9L, 1L, 
22L, 37L, 71L, 65L, 61L, 112L, 96L, 30L, 1L, 1L, 45L, 95L, 69L, 
81L, 117L, 130L, 121L, 25L, 5L, 63L, 73L, 80L, 82L, 114L, 144L, 
106L, 5L, 67L, 46L, 69L, 91L, 108L, 143L, 2L, 48L, 67L, 80L, 
89L, 120L, 2L, 54L, 83L, 79L, 82L, 5L, 56L, 62L, 99L, 3L, 43L, 
72L, 1L, 35L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Cohort", "Births", "Period", 
"Marriages", "Deaths"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -75L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
    Cohort = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Births = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Period = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Marriages = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Deaths = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("Cohort", "Births", "Period", 
"Marriages", "Deaths")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Now I would like to plot it by Cohort on the y-axis, by Period on the x-axis and by writing all three event counts as one data point respectively. In other words, I want to fill this simple plot here

```
plot(Lexisres$Period, Lexisres$Cohort)
```

with the respective birth, marriage, and death counts at each point - literally writing them down.

Something like this maybe:
[image]

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Aggregating data
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(Cohort, Period) %>% summarise(Births = sum(Births), Marriages = sum(Marriages), Deaths = sum(Deaths))

# Adding square and text coordinates
df$xmin <- df$Cohort
df$xmax <- df$Cohort+10
df$ymin <- df$Period
df$ymax <- df$Period+10
df$x_center <- (df$xmax+df$xmin)/2
df$y_center <- (df$ymax+df$ymin)/2

# Plotting five rectangles with lables
ggplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="Cohort") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name="Period") +
  geom_rect(data=df, mapping=aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), color="blue", alpha=0) +
  geom_text(data=df, aes(x_center, y_center, label=paste0("Births: ", Births, "\n", "Marriages: ", Marriages,"\n", "Deaths: ", Deaths)), size=2.5) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

## NOTE

By request the variables are pasted rather than summed.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Cohort, Period) %>% summarise(Births = paste(Births, collapse =","), Marriages = paste(Marriages, collapse =","), Deaths = paste(Deaths, collapse =","))
```

Data Used:

```
# Placing data in dataframe
df <- structure(list(Cohort = c(1760L, 1760L, 1760L, 1760L, 1760L, 
                          1760L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1770L, 1780L, 1780L, 
                          1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1780L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 
                          1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1790L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 
                          1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1800L, 1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 
                          1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 1810L, 1820L, 1820L, 1820L, 1820L, 
                          1820L, 1820L, 1820L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 1830L, 
                          1840L, 1840L, 1840L, 1840L, 1840L, 1850L, 1850L, 1850L, 1850L, 
                          1860L, 1860L, 1860L, 1870L, 1870L, 1870L, 1880L), Births = c(0L, 
                                                                                       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 
                                                                                       69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 
                                                                                       331L, 331L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 472L, 
                                                                                       508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 508L, 469L, 469L, 469L, 
                                                                                       469L, 469L, 469L, 469L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 595L, 
                                                                                       595L, 595L, 595L, 595L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 656L, 
                                                                                       361L, 361L, 361L, 1L), Period = c(1810L, 1820L, 1830L, 1840L, 
                                                                                                                         1850L, 1860L, 1810L, 1820L, 1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1810L, 
                                                                                                                         1820L, 1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1810L, 1820L, 
                                                                                                                         1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1810L, 1820L, 
                                                                                                                         1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1820L, 1830L, 
                                                                                                                         1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1830L, 1840L, 1850L, 
                                                                                                                         1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1840L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 
                                                                                                                         1890L, 1850L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1860L, 1870L, 1880L, 
                                                                                                                         1890L, 1870L, 1880L, 1890L, 1880L, 1890L, 1890L, 1890L), Marriages = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 34L, 3L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 67L, 236L, 24L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 160L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                272L, 35L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 207L, 251L, 45L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                0L, 0L, 137L, 296L, 34L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 184L, 330L, 35L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                0L, 2L, 255L, 289L, 49L, 0L, 0L, 174L, 429L, 53L, 0L, 232L, 538L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                0L, 0L, 361L, 1L), Deaths = c(5L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 5L, 3L, 13L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              25L, 24L, 44L, 33L, 6L, 13L, 21L, 28L, 39L, 40L, 44L, 9L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              22L, 37L, 71L, 65L, 61L, 112L, 96L, 30L, 1L, 1L, 45L, 95L, 69L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              81L, 117L, 130L, 121L, 25L, 5L, 63L, 73L, 80L, 82L, 114L, 144L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              106L, 5L, 67L, 46L, 69L, 91L, 108L, 143L, 2L, 48L, 67L, 80L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              89L, 120L, 2L, 54L, 83L, 79L, 82L, 5L, 56L, 62L, 99L, 3L, 43L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              72L, 1L, 35L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Cohort", "Births", "Period", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "Marriages", "Deaths"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ), row.names = c(NA, -75L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Cohort = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "collector")), Births = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "collector")), Period = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), Marriages = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), Deaths = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector"))), .Names = c("Cohort", "Births", "Period", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "Marriages", "Deaths")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: I took Penguins solution: ggplot(data = Lexisres) + geom_blank(aes(x = Period, y = Cohort)) + geom_text(aes(x = Period, y = Cohort, label = paste("\nDeaths: ", Deaths, "\nMarriages: ", Marriages)), size = 3.25, check_overlap = TRUE) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1900, 10)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1880, 10)) + theme_bw()

Comment: Allowing for a follow up? How would I include a first column that shows the births number not for every cohort period combination but for every cohort only? In other words, I want to add a column that displays the number of births for each cohort as those births do not change in a period.

Comment: Now yours looks much better Esben.

Comment: I achieved to bring the births in front like I want to have them. However, now the rest is smashed... ggplot(data = Lexisres) + geom_blank(aes(x = Period, y = Cohort)) + geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = Cohort, label = paste("\nBirths: ", Births))) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1900, 10)) + geom_text(aes(x = Period, y = Cohort, label = paste("\nDeaths: ", Deaths, "\nMarriages: ", Marriages)), size = 3.25, check_overlap = TRUE) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1900, 10)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1880, 10)) + theme_bw()

Comment: @Bengale I have added the one line you need to change to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) for this graph.

Please see the query below:

```
ggplot(data = Lexisres) + 
geom_text(aes(x = Period, 
              y = Cohort, 
              label = paste("B: ", Births, 
                           "\nD: ", Deaths, 
                           "\nM: ", Marriages)), 
                            size = 1.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Another solution showing how to use base R `plot()`

Showing as requested in the question:

1. "Cohort on the y-axis, by Period on the x-axis"
2. "respective birth, marriage, and death counts at each point - *literally writing them down*"

**UPDATED solution to sum Births, Marriages, Deaths** (as original data is not pre-aggregated)

---

```
# Aggregate data: sum all columns, group by Cohort+Period 
df <- aggregate(. ~ Cohort+Period, df, sum) 

tx=0.8  #variable to set the text scale for our labels

# Variable to tweak the x axis length on either side (by an extra half distance) 
extend_x <- diff(sort(unique(df$Period))[1:2])/2  # (difference of first two sorted(unique(x)) ) / 2

# Start a new plot
plot.new() 

# Set up x and y limits manually so we can control where they start & end  
plot.window(xlim = c( min(df$Period)-extend_x, max(df$Period)+extend_x), # x axis limits
            ylim = range(df$Cohort),  # y axis limits 
            xaxs = "i")  # xaxs = "i" sets x-axis to internal = match the original data range (avoids default, xaxs="r", that adds 4% to either side)

# Put text at each x, y point 
text( x=df$Period, y=df$Cohort, paste0(df$Births,":B"),    cex=tx, adj=c( 1.1, -0.1))  # 1=right justified, 0=align top (tweak by decimals)
text( x=df$Period, y=df$Cohort, paste0("M:",df$Marriages), cex=tx, adj=c(-0.1,  0.4))  # 0=left justified, 0.5=align middle (tweak by decimals)
text( x=df$Period, y=df$Cohort, paste0(df$Deaths,":D"),    cex=tx, adj=c( 1.1,  1.4))  # 1=right justified, 1=align bottom (tweak by decimals)

# Axis labels
axis(1, at=unique(df$Period))        # x-axis labels at all marks
axis(2, at=unique(df$Cohort),las=1)  # y-axis labels at all marks, `las=1` rotates the label to be horizontal

# Add x & y axis labels  
title(xlab="Period", ylab="Cohort")  

# Add grid lines
grid(length(unique(df$Period))+0,length(unique(df$Cohort))+0) 

box()  # draw a box around the plot
```

[image: plot output]

Comment: Updated solution to sum Births, Marriages, Deaths (as original data is not pre-aggregated for 1 pair of x/y points)